# Android: Использование JSON в приложение

Tags: gson, json, java, android

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, парсинг `JSON` нативным `org.json` происходит очень медленно, начал искать, нашел ответы ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830227/json-parsing-very-slow-in-android), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170552/parse-1-mb-json-on-android-very-slow)) где рекомендуют использовать `Gson` или `Jackson`. Может у кого есть замеры, насколько быстрее будет происходить разбор? Или может стоит отказаться от `JSON`, и использовать что нибудь другое для передачи данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данных много? Могу сказать что всегда парсил стандартными средствами объемы в несколько сотней записей из JSON-объектов каждый размеров вывода на 21-дюймсвый монитор и это занимало времени около от 3 до 5-7 секунд максимум.

Может быть проблема в скорости интернета? Как-то странно вообщем, сколько парсю json стандартной андроидовой штукой - ни разу не сталкивался с подобным.

Comment: @DroidAlex - парсится 6 секунд. Считая что близко к идеальному выполнены приложения gmail и vk - там, данных грузится больше, а парситься это почти мгновенно (у вк есть небольшие тормоза всё же, у gmail всё идеально).

Данных пока не много, 5-6 массивов, в каждом от 10 до 300-х объектов.

Comment: С чего Вы взяли, что там данных больше? Вполне возможно, что они подгружают даннные по запросу и потому мгновенно ) Усложняете заранее себе же работу, как мне кажется. "Преждевременная оптимизация - зло"(кто-то из великих)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на один вопрос был найден на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/187914/)

> Никто и подумать не мог, что на большом объеме данных старый добрый `JSON` превращается в тормознутую старушку…
> Первой реализацией парсера был нативный андроидовский — `JSONParser`, который показал себя не с лучшей стороны ещё до того, как загрузили реальный объем данных. Но когда загрузили… Получили от 15-90 сек парсинга, что было ой как не хорошо. Приэтом `JSONParser` съедал не так уж и мало памяти, порою заваливая приложение. Первым выходом из этого положения было увеличение «кучи» приложения, с помощью атрибута «`Large heap`». Но это не решало проблему со скоростью.
> Гуру андрода направили на путь истинный и скинули ссылку на репозиторий `https://github.com/johnkil/Android-JSONCompare`. На графиках и в семплах была приведена потенциальная скорость парсинга, но только рок — только хардкор! Для начала взялись за `JSON.simple` который по реализации внутри объектов не очень отличался от нативного, позволяя использовать его на лету без значительных изменений в коде. Результат оказался удручающим, как и следовало ожидать, при значительной нагрузке в 1000+ записей, `simple` начинал тупить ещё похуже `JSONParser`. Далее выбор пал на `GSON`, который в свою очередь по реализации то же был очень похож на нативный, что сразу же насторожило, учитывая предыдущий провал. Но все оказалось не так плохо! 90 сек превратились максимум 30. Но и это не устраивало никого, поэтому оставался один выбор — `Jackson`. Парсер своеобразный, в сравнении с предыдущими, но, методом проб и ошибок, мы всё-таки заставили его работать на себя. И были в шоке.
> Он показал себя даже лучше, чем во сне могло присниться. Предыдущие 30 сек канули в небытие и всплыли 3-5 сек.